# Integrating playwright into react jsx application for web crawler

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I set up a react jsx project with a front end. I am trying to use playwright as a web crawler and on the click of a button on the front end I am trying to execute playwright scripts. I generated this file (sample.js) for testing purposes

```
const { chromium } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch({
    headless: false
  });
  const context = await browser.newContext();

  // Open new page
  const page = await context.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://google.com');

  // ---------------------
  await context.close();
  await browser.close();
})();
```

There are 2 approaches I tried.

Approach 1.
I tried to turn it into a file with a method I can call from some other js file

```
import { chromium } from 'playwright';

const AutomationUtil = {
    testCall2: async () => {
        console.log('testing testCall async')
    }
}

export default AutomationUtil
```

but the moment I add the first line: "import { chromium } from 'playwright';"
it winds up trying to read a html file in node_modules/playwright and gives me the following error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/playwright-core/lib/webpack/recorder/index.html 1:0

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"><title>Playwright Inspector</title><script defer="defer" src="app.bundle.js"></script></head><body><div id="root"></div></body></html>
```

even when I install html loader and set up the rule in webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        fallback: { 
          path: false ,
          buffer: false,
          util: false,
          stream: false,
          constants: false,
          fs: false
        },
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: "html-loader",
            use: ["html-loader"],
          },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            test: /\.js|\.jsx$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
          },
        ],
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: "html-loader",
          },
        ],
    }
}
```

it gives me the same error

Approach 2.
I found that if I run **node sample.js** in the terminal it successfully executes the playwright script. So I tried using child process execSync to run a terminal command when the button on the front end is clicked

```
    testClick2 = () => {
        // AutomationUtil.testCall2()
        const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
        // import { execSync } from 'child_process';  // replace ^ if using ES modules

        const output = execSync('ls', { encoding: 'utf-8' });  // node sample.js will replace 'ls'
        console.log('Output was:\n', output);

    }
```

however, this gives me a **Uncaught TypeError: execSync is not a function** even though when I check in playwright, it is listed as a function. I tried other stackoverflow suggestions to try it with exec and it gives me the same type of error